# How can I implement the sitemaps for a TYPO3 Multidomainsystem when i have only one root folder?

Tags: seo, typo3, robots.txt, sitemap.xml

I have to link to both sitemap.xml in the robots.txt for a TYPO3 Multidomain System (.de and .com). 
There is one root folder for both instances.
How can i tell google which sitemap.xml is the right one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the name of the sitemap doesn't matter. Even directly using e.g. `eID=dd_googlesitemap` URLs is fine.

If you are not able to set up different web hosts with a separate `robots.txt` you can at least for Google manually [submit your sitemap URL through the Search Console Sitemaps tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en#addsitemap).